# Map method on geojson (Vuejs)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I need some help on the map method.
I got on a section somes array with a geoJson  and inside each array, some coordinates.

Example:

```
    section:
[0] -> geoJson -> coordinates -> (a lot of coordinates with index)
[1] -> geoJson -> coordinates -> (a lot of coordinates with index)
[2] -> geoJson -> coordinates -> (a lot of coordinates with index)
[3]............
..........
```

I need to group all of theses in one big array (To make polyline).
And i'm quite lost with the map method.

Have you some advice ? i'd like to use the map function.
Sorry for my english ( not the best one :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say if you have following array for section:

```
section = [{
  coordinates: [{index: 1, x: 1, y: 1}]
}];
```

The you can flatten it by using `map` function to get the coordinates and then `concat` function to merge them:

```
var merged = [].concat.apply([], section.map(x => x.geoJson.coordinates));
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. So the point is to get as result, something like this. [ [lat, lng], [lat, lnh], [lat, lng]..........] Try to understood the point of the map method, i understood  the concat one (ok, it's the easy one) but i'd like to understand the map one. :/ if you have some advice ??